# Can I add same wicket component under differrent parents in a markup page

Tags: java, html, wicket

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div wicket:id="id1">                        
                <div wicket:id="draggable" />
        </div>
    </td>   
    <td>
        <div wicket:id="id2">                        
                <div wicket:id="draggable"/>
        </div>
    </td> 
</tr>      
</table>
```

Consider the above markup, and on the java part I have simliar to the following..

```
WebMarkupContainer con1 = new WebMarkupContainer("id1");
WebMarkupContainer con2 = new WebMarkupContainer("id2");

Draggable draggable = new Draggable<Void>("draggable");

con1.add(draggable)
con2.add(draggable)
```

But when I navigate the page, I got a Wicket exception stating that "con1" doesn't have "draggable".

Did I miss something? Or fundamentally wrong? I am aware the it is not possible to add same markup under same parent. Is the any similar proper way to achieve that?

In addition, my objective is to create a Draggable component, that parallely drags over two items at a time.

Comment: You can have a component with the same id, but under different parents. The name is hierarchical, so A.B.draggable is different to A.C.draggable. That's allowed. You're using the same object twice. I'm not sure that's ok. Could be wrong though. Have you tried creating two draggable objects?
Can you post the actual exception stack trace?

Comment: creating two separate instances of Draggable, solved the exception, but now I am thinking of how to reflect one draggable's position to another [its a requirement] in the event of drag.

Comment: If you want to move two objects by dragging one of them, you could try experimenting with the jquery clone method. I recently did some prototyping with DnD, and got the behaviour you are looking for, although in my case it was unwanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a child component that has a parent to another parent will remove it from the first and add it to the second one. Thus the exception.

You need to create two separate instances of Draggable.

Usually draggable behavior is implemented with Wicket Behavior. You can reuse non-Ajax behaviors this way, i.e. you can add the same instance to several components.